# Unity - Class deriving from script containing MonoBehaviour is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop, inheritance

So, I have been stuck at this problem for a long time now. I have a class `PlayerScript` which derives from `Hittable`, which derives from `MonoBehaviour`. Problem is that Unity does not recognize this as a valid MonoBehaviour script.

```cs
public class Hittable : MonoBehaviour { //Code }

public class PlayerScript : Hittable { //More Code }
```

I have seen on multiple occasions that this should work, yet it doesn't. Can somebody point out to me why this doesn't work?

[image: The error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the metadata is mismached, usually happens when you try and rename both the file and the class. I would

1. Rename the file to something else and save it
   --(or copy it to an open doc)
2. delete the file with the old (desired) target name
3. remake the empty script through unity's menu with the desired name
4. copy the contents of the filled and renamed file onto the new file
5. make sure the pasted class matches the filename and then save
6. delete the file you copied from

Comment: Thank you, this solved my question. I will mark it as an answer in a few minutes when StackOverflow allows me

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just delete meta file of the script, it could delete some thins.